# How to write a Microsoft Excel file using PHP?

Tags: php

There are 8 columns that I want to save in the excel file. How do I use PHP to create, access and edit Microsoft Excel files?

Comment: did you try anything already? but ill give you a hint - csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel#phpexcel---openxml---read-write-and-create-spreadsheet-documents-in-php---spreadsheet-engine

Answer (score 3):

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is a library that can handle Excel files, and some other file formats. If you only have this 8 columns you than just set the data with

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Content');
...
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', 'Content');
```

And have a look at the hello word example, this will guide you how to create a simple xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

It provides some very cool features to manipulate Excel files. You can find a couple of examples here: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel is what you want, you can download from 
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Be careful when managing huge spreadsheets, because PHPExcel consumes lots of memory.

If you only need output a simple excel file with non formatted data, you can output the data in comma separated values (CSV)